# Kivy returning AttributeError: object has no attribute 'name' when it clearly has it

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I'm trying to build an interactive school timetable using Kivy but I keep running into problems with changing the Button text based on its name. I have created a grid layout where each button has a unique name, for example the first Button in Monday is `one_mon` the next one is `two_mon` and so on. I have created a class which inherits from `Button` and here is the Kivy and Python code for this class:

```
<Tile>:
    background_color: [.5, .9, 1, 1]
    halign: "center"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 96, 96
    text: self.lesson
    on_press: self.on_press()
    on_release: self.on_release()
```

Here is the Python code for Tile

```py
class Tile(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.lesson = ""
        self.sub_press = ""
        self.check()
        self.text = self.lesson

    def check(self):
        if self.name == "one_mon":
            self.text = "English"
            self.sub_press = "Room nr. 42 \n Mr. Hetman"

        ...        

        else:
            self.lesson = "None"
            self.sub_press = "None"

    def on_release(self):
        self.text = self.lesson
        self.background_color = [.5, .9, 1, 1]

    def on_press(self):
        self.text = self.sub_press
        self.background_color = [.01, .9, 1, 1]
```

Using `print(self.name)` under `on_press` function of `Tile` class works fine and returns the name of the button but using `if self.name == "one_mon"` raises an `AttributeError 'Tile' object has no attribute 'name'`

Here is the code for the parent widget holding all those buttons together:

```
<PlanChart>:
    cols: 11
    padding: 2
    Tile:
        id: one_mon
        name: "one_mon"
    Tile:
        id: two_mon
        name: "two_mon"
    Tile:
        id: three_mon
        name: "three_mon"

    ......

    Tile:
        id: ten_fri
        name: "ten_fri"
```

How can I assign a different text to a button based on its id or its name? I can't just assign the text to each button individualy becouse in the future I want to be able to switch beetwen diffrent students whose timetable might look diffrent.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `self.name`, it would search for a variable `name` within the `class` (which is not declared)

In order to access the id from the kv code, you need to do the following

```
if self.ids.one_mon.name == "one_mon"
```

hope it helps

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work :// Here is the error code `if self.ids.one_mon.name == "one_mon":
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 863, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`